# django debug toolbar Internal IP and static files

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I installed Django debug toolbar and configured it as explained in the docs. 
I am in local development configuration. As soon as I set up Internal IPs as indicated I get the following error

```
> FileNotFoundError at /admin/

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/odile/Documents/dev_logiciels/djangoE6000_techniques/E6000_stitch_techniques/static'
```

Settings.py is

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', ' E6000.pythonanywhere.com']
INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1']
......
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "E6000_stitch_techniques", "static"),
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

When I comment the line Internal-IPS I get no error but no debug bar.

ANy help welcomed.

Comment: have u added in urls.py

Comment: I have only urls.py at the project level because I have no website, just the admin.  I have added the code of the docs in the urls.py of the project level. I just created a urls.py at the app level and it does not help.

Comment: Do you actually have a file/directory at the path that the FileNotFound error is pointing to?